# margins of book class in latex

Tags: latex, margins

I would know which are the margins (in meters) top,right,bottom and left, default assigned for `book`class. there is a command or a way to know them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether you want to include the header/footer and possibly even if you use `twoside` document. Perhaps the following minimal working example can be a start:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{layouts}% http://ctan.org/pkg/layouts
\begin{document}
\pagevalues
\end{document}
```

uses the [`layouts` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/layouts) to produce

[image]

All units are printed in points by default, and there are 0.0351459 points per cm. Note that LaTeX does not use metres as a valid length.